# Evaluating closed path integral $\oint_C(aydx +2xydy)$ without greens theorem

Tags: integration, greens-theorem

The path is a rectangle in the x-y plane with vertices $(0,0), (a,0), (0,b),(a,b)$. How would I do this without greens theorem? I tried to parametrise it but that didn't work as I don't have functions of just $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Your coordinates aren't those of a rectangle. If they were you'd parameterize each edge separately. For instance a paramerization of the segment with initial point $(0,0)$ and terminal point $(a,0)$ is $x=t$, $y=0$, $0 \le t \le a$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Sorry I made the edit. And thanks I forgot about splitting it up!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Go forth and calculate!